# is that possible to change time trigger for azure functions without publishing (e.g. run all x minutes )?

Tags: c#, azure-functions

We are using timer triggered azure function with c#.
We must change the last time more often than the NCRON-expression.

e.g. run all 5 minutes ("0 */5 * * * *") instead all 10 minutes ("0 */10 * * * *")

We deploy with run from package (ZIP-Deploy).

Is this possible to change the NCRON-Expression without publishing and change it with the Azure portal or in server-files with FTP or similar?

Answer (score 1):

I have created the Azure Function App .NET 6 Timer Trigger of the CRON Expression `("0 */10 * * * *")`  with Zip Deploy. So, I cannot edit the CRON Expression as shown here:

[image]
[image]

[image]

> Is this possible to change the NCRON-Expression without publishing and change it with the Azure portal or in server-files with FTP or similar?

AFAIK,
To Edit the Timer Trigger Function App in Portal Menu, one of the workarounds is to write the CRON expression in `local.settings.json` file:

```
{
    "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet",
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "cron-expression":  "0 */10 * * * *"
  }
}
```

**Timer Trigger Function Code**:

```cs
 public void Run([TimerTrigger("%cron-expression%")] TimerInfo myTimer, ILogger log)
```

Publish using zip deploy to the Azure Portal Function App and create the app setting `cron-expression` to `0 */10 * * * *`.

**OR**

In the Publish Window of VS, click on ellipsis icon > Select `Manage Azure App Service Settings` > Whatever the setting you want to publish to Azure Function App such as CRON Expression - click on `Insert Value from local` > Ok > Publish the Function Project.

[image]

[image]

**After publishing for the 1st time, no need to publish for the change in CRON Expression, you can modify it using Azure Function App Configuration Menu**.

[image]

**After Modification through Azure portal**:

[image]

Comment: Thanks I can try it next week and give you feedback.